non-ASM statement in naked function
I am trying to create a class containing custom prologue/epilogues that shall be used by methods of other "consumer" classes.
It should look like the following example. (Keep in mind that these example prologue/epilogue bodies are just placeholders for illustration purposes. Surely they are going to be written in pure assembly)
class foo
{
    public:

    static inline void prologue(void) __attribute__ ((always_inline))
    {
        asm("nop");
    }
    

    static inline void epilogue(void) __attribute__ ((always_inline))
    {
        asm("nop");
    }

};


Now, in "consumer" classes that contain methods using these custom prologue/epilogues, I use the naked attribute like bellow. (Keep in mind this example method body structure is what matters. More code shall be placed between the prologue/epilogue but is not necessary for this illustration)
class bar
{
    public:
    static void method()  __attribute__ ((naked))
    {
        foo::prologue();
        //more cpp instructions shall go here
        foo::epilogue();
    }
};

The problem I am facing is that clang compiler does not allow calling standard Cpp code like foo::prologue() in naked functions and returns the following error
<source>:23:9: error: non-ASM statement in naked function is not supported
   23 |         foo::prologue();
      |         ^

Interestingly enough GCC seems to allows this.
Am I missing something? Is there any alternative elegant way to do this?
godbolt test can be found here: https://godbolt.org/z/YfnvfEM3f

Not sure what exactly you want to achieve calling an inline function from a naked function. Maybe just define foo_prologue() and foo_epilogue() macros?

Why is your example epilogue just nop without ret?  Are you intending that to be the actual epilogue in the assembly-function sense, restoring some call-preserved registers and returning?  Like chtz says, just use #define to expand a "string; of; asm; instructions" in multiple places.  The preprocessor runs before the compiler so can produce a string literal like you need for an asm() statement.

"GCC seems to allows this" - The docs are pretty unambiguous: Only basic asm statements can safely be included in naked functions. While using extended asm or a mixture of basic asm and C code may appear to work, they cannot be depended upon to work reliably and are not supported.

@DavidWohlferd Thanks for the comment. I am aware of the docs about this attribute and although I understand the disclaimer that it cannot be depended upon, at least I appreciate that the gcc compiled to completion and allows me to check the emmited assembly with a quick review.

@PeterCordes thanks for the comment. Using preprocessor macros is a typical way of doing this but I think it would solve half of the problem because I would have the same error if I tried to add more code between prologue and epilogue. Additionally, I intentionally chose to use a class so that in some sense some architecture specific functions would be formally defined and contained in a single place and keep consumer classes architecture agnostic. I am not sure if there is any other elegant way to do this though

Not if the "more code" was also GNU C Basic Asm statements like asm("mov x1, #123 \n" "add w1, w1, w1\n" ...);  Or expand CPP macros inside one big asm( prologue "code" epilogue ); asm statement and define them as just strings.  Double-quoted strings separated only by spaces are implicitly pasted together into one longer string by the compiler; this is how multi-line asm statements are normally written.  (Although the recent C++ language R"() allows embedded newlines.)

and keep consumer classes architecture agnostic - how does that work when the consumer has to itself be hand-written in asm since it's a naked function?  Are you planning to paste together multiple blocks of asm to make different functions?  That would normally miss optimization opportunities, which raises the question of why use asm or naked functions at all?

You could have different arch-specific files that you #include as appropriate to get definitions for building-block macros that work for the right ISA.  Maybe have your build system use -I .../x86-64  or -I .../aarch64 so #include "asm-stuff.h" pulls in the right definitions.  Or some other way of dispatching, like a wrapper header that uses #ifdef macros to select the right #include.  Or that's generated as part of your build with the right #include.

how does that work when the consumer has to itself be hand-written in asm since it's a naked function? - Lets pretend for a while that the method did not have the "naked" attribute. Then, the bar class would be pure CPP. Prologues and epilogues from foo class would be perfectly unlined and I would be free to add "more code" in standard CPP. The bar class would be platform agnostic since it does not contain any assembly and just depends on foo to have correct implementations of the pro/epiloguesand does not contain any assembly.

Now, since a custom prologue/epilogue is present in said method we need to not allow the copiler to create its own prologues epilogues. This AFAIK is only accomplished with the "naked" attribute. But the naked attribute comes with its own contraints allowing nothing but assembly and this is where thing get problematic. Because in principle the scheme works but it is the side-effects of naked attribute that get in the way. This is what I am trying to circumvent somehow or alternatively  learn some completely different approach of solving this

What use-case do you have in mind for this?  What's an actual example of asm that you want the compiler to emit that you can't come close enough to with pure C++?  The prologue has to reserve enough stack space for the local variables (and potentially temporaries) in the function body, and has to save the call-preserved regs the compiler chooses to use.  So there's no simple way to just use your own prologue with a compiler-generated function body without obvious correctness problems (or massive inefficiency like saving/restoring everything and allocating tons of stack space.)

Unlike Clang, GCC doesn't enforce the restriction of only Basic Asm statements in naked functions, in case you want to play around with it and see how easy it is to make broken code that e.g. violates the ABI and breaks its callers, or for i386 -fPIC tries to use EBX as a pointer to the GOT when your prologue didn't set that up.  (There are I think other ISAs that lack easy PC-relative addressing and also want a register set up in the prologue for position-independent code.)

What use-case do you have in mind for this? - I want to build a custom scheduler. The naked function is supposed to run as an interrupt handler where the scheduler selects which task is to be executed next(this is the "more code" part). This means that the interrupt prologue needs to store everything so that the interrupted task can be resumed in the future. If there is a way to force the compiler to store everything in its prologue It would be interesting but I doubt that this is possible

Didn't see your reply since you didn't @ notify me.  Normally you just write the interrupt entry-point in asm can call a C function that follows the normal calling convention.  Or there's __attribute__((interrupt("type"))) on ARM, and __attribute__((interrupt)) on a few other targets including RISC-V and x86.  (https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#interrupt-arm).  Note the caveats, like *Interrupt handlers should only call functions with the ‘no_caller_saved_registers’ attribute, or should be compiled with the ‘-mgeneral-regs-only’ flag to avoid saving unused non-GPRs.

By nature, naked function doesn't allow C++ statement because you don't have any setups for stack, registers or addresses.
For a workaround, you can call function as extern C symbols for ARM instruction which you can pass in your ASM.inside of your naked function.
class foo {
public:
    static inline void prologue(void) __attribute__((always_inline)) {
        asm("nop");
    }

    static inline void epilogue(void) __attribute__((always_inline)) {
        asm("nop");
    }
};

extern "C" void foo_prologue_wrapper() {
    foo::prologue();
}

extern "C" void foo_epilogue_wrapper() {
    foo::epilogue();
}

extern "C" void foo_otherfunctioncall(){
    //code the rest here
    return;
}

class bar {
public:
    static void method() __attribute__((naked)) {
        asm volatile(
            "bl foo_prologue_wrapper\n"  
            "bl foo_otherfunctioncall\n"
            "bl foo_epilogue_wrapper\n"  
            "ret\n"                      
        );
    }
};

int main(void) {
    bar::method();
    return 0;
}

With this, you should be able to access your C++ inside of the "foo_otherfunctioncall" function.
#include <vector>

extern "C" void foo_otherfunctioncall(){
    std::vector<int> a;
    return;
}

It does compile into this :
foo_prologue_wrapper:
        nop
        ret

foo_epilogue_wrapper:
        nop
        ret

foo_otherfunctioncall:
        sub     sp, sp, #48
        stp     x29, x30, [sp, #32]
        add     x29, sp, #32
        add     x0, sp, #8
        str     x0, [sp]
        bl      std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>::vector() [base object constructor]
        ldr     x0, [sp]
        bl      std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>::~vector() [base object destructor]
        ldp     x29, x30, [sp, #32]
        add     sp, sp, #48
        ret

main:
        sub     sp, sp, #32
        stp     x29, x30, [sp, #16]
        add     x29, sp, #16
        mov     w8, wzr
        str     w8, [sp, #8]
        stur    wzr, [x29, #-4]
        bl      bar::method()
        ldr     w0, [sp, #8]
        ldp     x29, x30, [sp, #16]
        add     sp, sp, #32
        ret

bar::method():
        bl      foo_prologue_wrapper
        bl      foo_otherfunctioncall
        bl      foo_epilogue_wrapper
        ret

__clang_call_terminate:
        stp     x29, x30, [sp, #-16]!
        mov     x29, sp
        bl      __cxa_begin_catch
        bl      std::terminate()

DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0:
        .xword  __gxx_personality_v0


AArch64 passes the return address in a register, which you need to save/restore to be able to return to your own caller, rather than to just after bl foo_epilogue_wrapper.  You could restore it then b epilogue.  You could look at this as a tailcall, or that epilogue is where the ret for method lives.  The epilogue of a function normally restores registers and returns.

Note that the OP was trying to use __attribute__ ((always_inline)) on their prologue and epilogue, probably to make it possible to use the same prologue and epilogue in multiple functions to save/restore the same set of registers.  Making them actual functions is more overhead than you want.  They could use the C preprocessor to #define strings of asm text.

Thanks for the comments. This is an interesting approach. The problem with this is that as mentioned in another comment the ultimate goal would be to design this so that the bar class does not contain any architecture specific code (i.e. assembly) but utilize methods in foo class that actually are architecture specific

Unfortunately, you won't be able to run C++ code directly in the naked function, maybe the solution of @PeterCordes can be a workaround too. Avoiding architecture specific code would necessary means avoid naked function. Maybe try looking arround _attribute__((optimize("O0"))) that reduce the optimization at the lowest level. Just ensure to keep track of the memory stack as you're now obligated to manage it manually.
